# Algorithm that finds points from scatterplot that align best to middle of grid boxes

Tags: typescript, algorithm, scatter-plot

I have a simple 2D scatter plot with random points all over the place. Suppose I overlay an invisible grid over it that is X rectangles by Y rectangles where each rectangle is of equal size.

Like in this (hand drawn) example image, X and Y are both 6:

[image]

What I'm trying to figure out is this:

- Return all points that exist in a rectangle and are closest to the middle of that rectangle.

Keep in mind that some rectangles will have no points in them at all. In the example image above, I would expect 9 points (one point for each rectangle that has points in it).

---

## Why

The reason I want to figure this out is because I have a scatterplot with many points (100k) and each point has an image associated with it.

My user wants to see a uniform display of the images but I can't show all 100k images. So, my solution was to think of a grid overlaying the plot and then showing the one image that exists closest to the middle of each rectangle in the plot. Then, if the users zooms in or out I can recompute the grid and show the images based on the new grid.

I'm using plotly, react, and typescript.